# Decaying Fourier transform and smoothness

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integral-transforms

Suppose that $f\in L^1 (\mathbb{R})$ and that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is $C_n > 0$ such that its Fourier transform satisfies
$$
|\hat{f}(\xi )| \le C_n(1+|\xi |^2)^{-n}.
$$
I want to show that $f\in C^\infty (\mathbb{R})$.

By the inversion formula we have
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi } \int \limits _\mathbb{R} \hat{f}(\xi ) e^{ix\xi } \, d\xi ,
$$
but as far as I can see this is only valid almost everywhere. Clearly the right hand side is continuous since $\hat{f}\in L^1$ (and even smooth), but my problem is that the formula is just an identity in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Why is $f$ necessarily continuous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, what we have to show is that in the equivalence class of $f$ for equality almost everywhere, there is a smooth function. Inversion formula gives that $g\colon x\mapsto \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\widehat f(\xi)e^{i\xi x}d\xi$ is in this equivalence class, so what we have to show that is that $g$ is smooth.

The decay condition used with dominated convergence theorem allows us to show that 
$$g^{(d)}(x)=\frac 1{2\pi}i^d\int_\Bbb R\widehat f(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\xi^dd\xi,$$
which is a differentiable function.

Comment: Yes, perhaps that is how I should think of the problem, not like I am given a fixed representative to begin with. Thank you.

Comment: You are using the fact that$$\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto (1+x\cdot x)^{-n}$$is integrable for all $n\geq 1$, aren't you? And this follows from the fact that the function$$\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto(1+x\cdot x)^{-1}$$ is integrable by applying the dominated convergence theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: @Filippo Integrability of $1/(1+x^2)^n$ indeed play a crucial role, but there is no need to use the dominated convergence theorem, simply from $1/(1+x^2)^n\leq 1/(1+x^2)$,

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thank you for the confirmation!