# Question related to decay of Fourier transform and smoothness

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose $f\in L^1 (\mathbb{R})$ and that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is $C_n > 0$ such that its Fourier transform satisfies
$$
|\hat{f}(\xi )| \le C_n(1+|\xi |^2)^{-n}.
$$
Let 
$$g(x) = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\widehat f(\xi)e^{i\xi x}d\xi$$ 
and suppose we want to show that $g$ is smooth.

The decay condition allows us to show that the function
$$k_d(x)=\frac 1{2\pi}i^d\int_\Bbb R\widehat f(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\xi^dd\xi$$
is well defined for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

How does it then follow that the $d$-th derivative of $g(x)$ is in fact $k_d(x)$?

This question is related to the answer provided in [Decaying Fourier transform and smoothness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251533/decaying-fourier-transform-and-smoothness?rq=1). It says it follows by the dominated convergence theorem but I was not sure how this was the case... I would greatly appreciate some explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider the case $d=1$. Use the _definition_ of $g'$.

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am still not quite seeing where the dominated convergence theorem comes into play... Could you possibly explain to me this bit by any chance? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnnyT. Well, what do you get when you take the definition of the derivative and insert that into the definition of $g$? You get $g'=$ what?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich One gets that $g' = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(\psi) e^{i x \xi } (e^{i (x+h) \xi} - 1) d \xi$... I get it now. Thank you very much for all of your help!! :D